# Use Loki and Grafana to implement Full Text Search?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, victoriametrics, logql

I have multiple log files, thus my loki stream looks like:

```
{job="my_job", filename="20230920_1.log"}
{job="my_job", filename="20230920_2.log"}
```

I generate these files each day at 16pm. And in each file it should has 2 sentences **simulate from** and **error=0**

I use Loki and Grafana to monitor my logs. So now I want to config a alert. For example, each day at 17pm after these files are generated, the alert should check all files and see if any file does not has these 2 sentences.

I'm new to Loki and LogQL, and as far as I know LogQL is used to **query each line in one stream.** Anyway hope this is not a useless question.

Besides, if Loki does not fit in this problem, is there something else do? (VictoriaMetrics...?)